# C++ QListView with icons And Signals on items clicked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlistview

I have a QListview where I have set a model. The model contains the QList. Now I want to get the contents of QListview on clicking the item. But I don't know how to do this? Through some tutorials I followed I am able to get two items appear in the QListview as follows. But I dont know how to make it work?? Please anyone help. The code which I am working as follows.

```
listviewmodel =new QListView;
listviewmodel->setModel( createModel() );
listviewmodel->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
listviewmodel->setIconSize(QSize(size().width()/8, size().height()/8));

connect(listviewmodel,SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(ItemClicked(QModelIndex)));

QAbstractItemModel *MainWindow::createModel()
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();

    QList<QStandardItem *> listItem;

    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem();
    item2->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(qimages2)));
    listItem << item2;


    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem();
    item1->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(qimages1)));
    listItem << item1;

    model->appendColumn(listItem);

return model;

}


void MainWindow::ItemClicked (QModelIndex index )
{    
   textEdit->setText(index.data().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in QtCreator and it works as you described. So what is the problem? Are you getting some errors? Maybe did you not put declaration of `ItemClicked(QModelIndex)` below the `public slots:`? Are you sure that `connect` returns true? Try to check it:

```
bool success = connect(listviewmodel,SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(ItemClicked(QModelIndex)));
Q_ASSERT(success);
```

> EDIT: If you want to display only icons at `QListView` and get some text informations after clicking on specified item, you can do it in the following way:

```
item2->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(qimages2)));
item2->setData("informations about item2", Qt::UserRole);

(...)

void MainWindow::ItemClicked (QModelIndex index )
{
    QString data = index.data(Qt::UserRole).value<QString>();
    ui->textEdit->setText(data);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I had my ItemClicked() function in private slots. But I don think that is the problem. Actually, as I told earlier, I have images icon in my Listview so whenever i clicked any image icon, i want the information and details behind it. But I am getting nothing on clicking. the text edit is empty.

Comment: But what informations do you want to display in `textEdit`? It's obvious that this field remains empty if you didn't set text in list items.